# what would cause ecs service to fail on launch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I notice my ecs task is getting killed with an event message

> service example was unable to place a task because no container
>   instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching
>   container-instance d43b363c-dcc9-4e82-90f0-6346d9f25af3 doesn't have
>   the agent connected.

I see this when I deploy docker images when doing service update with `force new deployment`

And the metrics graph look like the following. 
I can't ssh in to the instance (I guess because cpu is too busy)

It's not all of the ecs, If I deploy two instances (with one task each), one succeeds and one fails.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1874

Comment: does the new instance is from same AMI? does have both updated ecs agent?

Comment: yes they are running same ami and ecs agent, because they are launched from autoscaling group agent version 1.31.0, and ami `amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20190913-x86_64-ebs (ami-02897256becb517d3)`

Comment: did you check the ecs agent log? seems like the issue is from ecs agent

Comment: I tried to , I think I have to ssh in to check the log, but I couldnt.... I guess I'll wait some more time hopfully waiting for cpu to settle down

Comment: you CPU seems not fine, it seems like there is process that is crashing and keep the cpu high. remove the new service and the cpu will get down automaticly and then check the ECS agent logs